# is there a way to construct a pattern that would trigger when an expression is used as a held/unevaluated in some form?

Tags: evaluation

For example, consider the following code

```
f[x_] := (Print["evaluated f"]; workWith[x]);
```

We use it, then f evaluates:

```
f[x]
(* evaluated f, workWith[x] *)
```

When we use f in the assignment, f does not evaluate:

```
f[x] = 1
(* 1 *)
```

Is it possible to construct a pattern that will detect cases when f[x] is used unevaluated like in the Set command? For example, one could do

```
f /: Set[f[x_], rhs___] := somework when f is not evaluated
```

but that would only work specifically for the Set command. Is there a way to make it more generic?, for example like this

```
HeldExpression[f[x_]] := somework when f is not evaluated
```

would be great but, of course, HeldExpression does not exist.

I realized that

```
f /: HoldPattern[_[___,f[x_],___]] := work with f when used
```

actually triggers even if f is used in the context of the Set command, but it does not discriminate between to be evaluated (y=f[x];) and not to be evaluated (f[x]=1;) scenarios.

Regards
Zoran

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what is your goal at the end but the following works quite well:

```
$Pre = Function[{x},
                If[Count[Hold[x], HoldPattern[f[_]], ∞] =!= 0, Print["test"]]; x,
                HoldAll]
```

> [image]

Functions like `$Pre`, `$Post` etc give nice effects but use them wisely.

Comment: thanks! exactly on the right track, if not the solution! I wonder, imagine a scenario where Pre is redefined someplace else (it is global variable right?). I supose one could use Protect[Pre]. Is there another way, without using global variables like Pre? Just curious...

Comment: @zorank Not sure if what you need but you can use `Block` to play with `$Pre` only there.

Comment: That would not work. I am developing a utility package that needs that functionality. The package has to be used with other packages, and then it would define $Pre for everyone else, and they might not like it. That is the reason why I would like to avoid use of global variables. Another issue, I worry about the speed. My feeling is that having a pattern like match would be much faster then digging through every expression every time to find occurences of OBJ@f.

Comment: @zorank you can set *levelspec* for `Count`. This is pattern matching so I;m not sure what you are after. About scope, yes, that may be a problem. Maybe getting a package could set ``Global``` context to be restricted to particular notebook so it would not spread over?

Comment: Very kind of you to try to help. I wonder, if one sets levelspec for Count it might miss some occurences, right? I would like to have a localized pattern mathcing definition that the user will never really see. that's all. changing `$Pre` makes me very, very nervous. I will rather stick to the `HoldPattern[_[___,f[_],___]]` idea. That can be made very local. Though I am not sure how costly it is, i.e. this pattern is so generic that it might be tested a larger number of times.

Comment: @zorank I'm sorry, I can't focus on this now. I'll reply in about 4h.